# "COMPLETE_FILL_FAILED"error while using 0x Protocol V2 to exchange ERC1155 tokens

Tags: 0x, erc-1155

I am using 0x protocol V2 forwarder contract.
And it's fine to exchange ERC721 token through function marketBuyOrdersWithEth,
yet when I tried to exchange ERC1155 tokens,
it keeps showing the [error][1] COMPLETE_FILL_FAILED.

I think the params should be correct. So I was wondering if V2 is able to exchange ERC1155 token.

```
const handleSign = async () => {
const { orderHashUtils, assetDataUtils, signatureUtils } = await import(
  "@0x/order-utils"
)
const { ecSignOrderAsync } = signatureUtils
const erc1155Data = assetDataUtils.encodeERC1155AssetData(
  "0xA8009103f9a4f297BBC313B74b6A8f46d9323E8E",
  [BigNumber.from(1)],
  [BigNumber.from(1)],
  "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
)


const erc20Data = assetDataUtils.encodeERC20AssetData("0xc778417e063141139fce010982780140aa0cd5ab")
const ts = Date.now()
const salt = ts.toString()

const expirationTimeSeconds = Math.floor((ts + 60 * 60 * 1e3) / 1e3).toString()

const order = {
  makerAssetAmount: "1",
  makerAssetData: erc1155Data,
  takerAssetAmount: "1",
  takerAssetData: erc20Data,
  makerAddress: account,
  exchangeAddress: process.env.EXCHANGE,
  salt,
  expirationTimeSeconds,
  feeRecipientAddress: AddressZero,
  takerAddress: AddressZero,
  senderAddress: AddressZero,
  makerFee: "0",
  takerFee: "0",
}
const zeroXProvider = await import("@0x/subproviders").then(
  ({ MetamaskSubprovider }) => new MetamaskSubprovider(provider))
const { signature } = await ecSignOrderAsync(
  zeroXProvider,
  order,
  account,
)
setSign(signature)
setOrder(order)}
```

}

```
const fillOrder = () => {
const fContract = new web3.eth.Contract(fABI, process.env.FORWARDER)
const args = [
  [order],
  1,
  [sign],
  [],
  [],
  0,
  AddressZero,
]
// marketBuyExactAmountWithWeth
fContract.methods
  .marketBuyOrdersWithEth(...args)
  .send({ from: account, value: web3.utils.toWei("1", "ether") })
  .on("transactionHash", (hash) => {
    console.log(hash)
  })
  .on("receipt", (receipt) => {
    console.log(receipt)
  })
  .on("error", (error) => {
    console.log(error)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
  })
```

}

Thanks for your answering!
[1]: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x810ef051ebae1a18e0887410c1a273cb6072b04ea262bfd9953065d932a620ca

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe ERC1155 is supported in 0xV2 forwarder contract. The good news is that we've recently shipped ERC721, ERC1155 and ETH buying support in 0x v4.

A developer friendly, community developed package called Trader SwapSDK can be [found here.](https://docs.swapsdk.xyz/)